# Error: Declaration terminated incorrectly

Tags: c++, declaration

I get the error in this part of the code:

```
void baklanges(list<MataIn> lista);
{
int n = text.length();
for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
   char temp = text.at(i);
   text.at(i) = text.at(n-1-i);
   text.at(n-1-i)= temp;
}
cout<<"Texten baklanges:\n"<<text<<endl;
}
```

I don't see any problem in the code,does any of you?

Comment: Next time, please remember to tell us on what line the error is occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this semicolon.

```
void baklanges(list<MataIn> lista);
                                  ^
```

Comment: thnx man,I always miss these details after working for so long on a code :P